# linalg.solve() iteration over dictionaries

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, iteration

Here's the context: I have to produce a mix of different products.
I don't want to produce them in single lots for each product, but instead I want to make lots as small and as homogenous as possible, with each lot containing a small amount of the total production.

For each product I know the demand:

```
demands = {'p1': 140, 'p2': 220, 'p3': 275, 'p4': 320, 'p5': 60}
```

I know the time (min) in which my plant is operative:

```
tdisp = 460
```

I calculate the production rate (min/piece) for each product:

```
tts = {p: tdisp/demands[p] for p in demands}
```

I compute the maximum number of lots I can fit in the given time, considering the length of one lot as the time needed to produce the slowest part:

```
n_seq = math.ceil(tdisp/max(tts.values()))
```

I then consider the ratio between the length of one lot and the production rate of each product, to see how many pieces of each product I can fit in one lot:

```
tt_ratios = {p: max(tts.values())/tts[p] for p in tts}
```

The values are not integers in many cases, but they must be, because we are talking about single pieces!
So I compute bot the upper and lower values:

```
tt_ratios_ceil = {p: math.ceil(tt_ratios[p]) for p in tt_ratios}
tt_ratios_floor = {p: math.floor(tt_ratios[p]) for p in tt_ratios}
```

If I produce according to ceil, I will have overproduction, if I produce according to floor I will not match the demand.
So I have to produce floor for a certain amount of lots and ceil for the remaining part.
What I want to do is to solve, for each product, a system like this:

```
n*x +N*y = demands[part]
x + y = n_seq
```

with n being the lower case and N the upper case, and x, y the respective number of sequences.

This is the full code:

```
import math
import numpy as np

demands = {'p1': 140, 'p2': 220, 'p3': 275, 'p4': 320, 'p5': 60}
tdisp = 460
tts = {p: tdisp/demands[p] for p in demands}
n_seq = math.ceil(tdisp/max(tts.values()))
tt_ratios = {p: max(tts.values())/tts[p] for p in tts}

tt_ratios_ceil = {p: math.ceil(tt_ratios[p]) for p in tt_ratios}
tt_ratios_floor = {p: math.floor(tt_ratios[p]) for p in tt_ratios}

splits = {}
for p in tt_ratios:
    if tt_ratios[p] != 1:
        split = np.linalg.solve([[tt_ratios_floor[p], tt_ratios_ceil[p]], [1, 1]], [demands[p], n_seq])
    else:
        split = n_seq
    splits.update({p: {'min': [tt_ratios_floor[p], split[0]], 'max': [tt_ratios_ceil[p], split[1]]}})

print(splits)
```

But this is the result I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\logistic_management_tool\try.py", line 19, in

splits.update({p: {'min': [tt_ratios_floor[p], split[0]], 'max': [tt_ratios_ceil[p],split[1]]}})

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Problem here is when you set `split` to `n_seq` (an int), then try to call `split[1]` when updating the dictionary.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I didn't see it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is in the `else` clause, where you set `split` to an `int`. Indeed, you then try to call `split[1]` right after, thus getting an error.
A solution to this problem is to duplicate the `splits.update` instruction and modify it to work with an `int`, as described below:

```py
if tt_ratios[p] != 1:
    split = np.linalg.solve([[tt_ratios_floor[p], tt_ratios_ceil[p]], [1, 1]], [demands[p], n_seq])
    splits.update({p: {'min': [tt_ratios_floor[p], split[0]], 'max': [tt_ratios_ceil[p], split[1]]}})
else:
    split = n_seq
    splits.update({p: {'min': [tt_ratios_floor[p], split], 'max': [tt_ratios_ceil[p], split]}})
```